# JQuery binding click event issue

Tags: jquery

im trying to bind five different elements with a click event having the same function as a event handler but with different parameters. Heres is my code:

```
$("#areaascensor").bind("click", setearImagen("ascensor"));
$("#areaflat").bind("click", setearImagen("flat"));
$("#areaduplex").bind("click", setearImagen("duplex"));
$("#areasimple").bind("click", setearImagen("simple"));
$("#areatendales").bind("click", setearImagen("tendales"));
```

the problem is that when i click any of the elements, it allways jumps the last event. in this case setearImagen("tendales"). dont know why :( any clue?

here is the div im using

```
<div class="morph-button morph-button-large" id="coordenadas">
<area shape="rect" id="areaflat" coords="129, 50, 381, 152" href="#" style="border: 1px solid;" data-maphilight="{" strokecolor":"000000","strokewidth":1,"fillcolor":"0000ff","fillopacity":0.4}"=""> 
<area shape="rect" id="areaduplex" coords="129, 154, 383, 283" href="#" style="border: 1px solid;" data-maphilight="{" strokecolor":"000000","strokewidth":1,"fillcolor":"0000ff","fillopacity":0.4}"=""> 
<area shape="rect" id="areasimple" coords="129, 286, 391, 364" href="#" style="border: 1px solid;" data-maphilight="{" strokecolor":"000000","strokewidth":1,"fillcolor":"0000ff","fillopacity":0.4}"=""> 
<area shape="rect" id="areatendales" coords="141, 6, 362, 31" href="#" style="border: 1px solid;" data-maphilight="{" strokecolor":"000000","strokewidth":1,"fillcolor":"0000ff","fillopacity":0.4}"=""> 
<area shape="rect" id="areaascensor" coords="240, 368, 278, 523" href="#" style="border: 1px solid;" data-maphilight="{" strokecolor":"000000","strokewidth":1,"fillcolor":"0000ff","fillopacity":0.4}"="">
```

i already tried with .on and .click but still the same problem

here is setearImagen

```
function setearImagen(tipo){
    if(tipo == "flat"){
        $("#interiorImg").html('');
        $("#interiorImg").append('<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B9LTjyArujnXUVlCM0FIQUZ1UDg" alt="" width="800" height="500" style="padding-right:10px;"/>');
        $("#interiorImg").append('<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B9LTjyArujnXRVY3bEpmVThkVk0" alt="" width="400" height="500"/>');
        $("#descripcionDepa").text('Apartamento Flat');
    }else if(tipo == "duplex"){
        $("#interiorImg").html('');
        $("#interiorImg").append('<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B9LTjyArujnXM3ZTdU1MTkRCT3c" alt="" width="800" height="500" style="padding-right:10px;"/>');
        $("#interiorImg").append('<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B9LTjyArujnXNjc0ajh3bEM2eTg" alt="" width="400" height="500" style="padding-right:10px;"/>');
        $("#descripcionDepa").text('Apartamento Duplex');
    }else if(tipo == "simple"){
        $("#interiorImg").html('');
        $("#interiorImg").append('<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B9LTjyArujnXSmFwaTZ2SGVNSE0" alt="" width="800" height="500" style="padding-right:10px;"/>');
        $("#interiorImg").append('<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B9LTjyArujnXcThRcXhveTVlams" alt="" width="400" height="500" style="padding-right:10px;"/>');
        $("#descripcionDepa").text('Apartamento Simple');
    }else if(tipo == "tendales"){
        $("#interiorImg").html('');
        $("#interiorImg").append('<img src="undefined" alt="" width="800" height="500" style="padding-right:10px;"/>');
        $("#interiorImg").append('<img src="undefined" alt="" width="400" height="500" style="padding-right:10px;"/>');
        $("#descripcionDepa").text('Tendales');
    }else if(tipo == "ascensor"){
        $("#interiorImg").html('');
        $("#interiorImg").append('<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B9LTjyArujnXMVRuZHlQdVVzSGM" alt="" width="800" height="500" style="padding-right:10px;"/>');
        $("#interiorImg").append('<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0B9LTjyArujnXNkUyVW1PMjRhSlE" alt="" width="400" height="500" style="padding-right:10px;"/>');
        $("#descripcionDepa").text('Ascensor');
    }
}
```

Comment: are any of the elements inside of any of the other elements? maybe you need to show us some of your html

Comment: Can you post a complete code example please?

Comment: My guess without seeing code is that maybe your event is bubbling up the dom. Depending on what edition of jquery you use, you have 2 different binding methods. if it's jquery 1.7 or lower use bind, if it's greater, use .on

Comment: I avoid jquery binding with params like the plague.  Most others and I add the param as an attr to the html element. Then read in that value.

Comment: Also wondering if those id's are generated dynamically. You may need event delegation as well

Comment: Please can you post the `setearImagen` function.

Comment: hi @DLeh the elements are inside a div.

Comment: @ed_dac i tried .click .bind .on is the same :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're binding the click event to the result of the method that's called on the right -- that is, if you have params after the function name then javascript is going to immediately invoke that function, and the bind is going to expect that function to return another function that can handle the click event. If you want to pass params to the method they should be in a separate object passed after the event name, thus:

```
$('selector').bind('click', {arg: val}, setearImagen);
```

You can [read more about it here](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/)

Comment: hi, thx for the answer. im tryin $("#areatendales").on("click", {value: "tendales"} ,setearImagen); but it results in an error. is that what u mean?

Comment: Yeah, but you'll have to change setearImagen too because it'll now take an event as an argument, not the value you originally intended. You should read the link for more info.

Comment: But now that I've looked at your code, you're pulling your hair out for nothing. Please, just write separate handlers, one per case, and stop using the parameter and `if` statements -- it's just poor code.

Comment: u were so right, i did it separate and it works fine!!! Thanks. Anyway i still wanna know why doesnt work the other way, if u have any other clue ill appreciate it

Comment: Thanks -- if you can tick my answer and upvote it'd be helpful :)

Comment: Also, like I said, you need to write event handlers to deal with the response to events like click, but you just had a method which didn't pay attention to the event data. The `tipo` variable in your method isn't a string, as you suppose, it's an event!